# Java lambda stream merge parameters in model

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I cant find answer.
I try to merge multiple Object to one.
Example model

```
public class Model {
    private List<Map<String, Object>> param1;
    private List<String> param2;
}
```

In my code, I convert another data to model.

```
List<Model> models = models2.stream()
    .map(Optional::get)
    .map(model2 -> convert(model2))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I try to aggregate converted list of models to one Model.
Like:

```
Model model = models2.stream() ...etc
```

but I dont know how.

Comment: what does your object of which `models2` is a collection look like?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to add a `merge` method to your `Model` class:

```
public class Model {
    private List<HashMap<String, Object>> param1;
    private List<String> param2;

    public Model merge (Model other) {
        this.param1.addAll(other.param1);
        this.param2.addAll(other.param2);

        return this;
    }
}
```

And then `reduce` your stream:

```
Model allInOne = models2.stream()
    .map(Optional::get)
    .map(model2 -> convert(model2))
    .reduce(Model::merge)
    .get();
```

That `merge` method can also be a `static Model merge (Model first, Model second)` or externalized `BinaryOperator<Model>` function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your current code contains a **hidden unobvious bug**. The operation `Optional::get` will throw an exception when an empty `Optional` met. You should filter out the empty optionals first:

```
// ...
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.map(Optional::get)
// ...
```

Or if you're using `java-9` or above you can simply flat-map the optional values:

```
// ...
.flatmap(Optional::stream)
// ...
```

---

As for your question, it looks like you need to `reduce` with a *merge-function*. There are different ways to define that function:

1. Method reference:

   ```
   private Model merge(Model model1, Model model2) {
       // merge model2 to model1
       return model1;
   }

   Model model = models2.stream()
           .filter(Optional::isPresent)
           .map(Optional::get)
           .map(this::convert)
           .reduce(this::merge)
           .orElse(defaultModel);
   ```
2. A `BinaryOperator` stored in a variable:

   ```
   BinaryOperator<Model> merge = (model1, model2) -> { /* do smth */; return model1;}  

   // ... 
   .map(this::convert)
   .reduce(merge)
   //
   ```
3. Inline `lambda`

   ```
   // ... 
   .map(this::convert)
   .reduce((model1, model2) -> { /* do smth */; return model1;})
   //
   ```

---

IMHO the first option is the best one. Having a separate method will make your code cleaner and easier to maintain.